# PHP preg_replace backreference causing undefined constant notice

Tags: php, regex, camelcasing

I'm trying to use NameCase a php class on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/lastname/).  When I run it I get this notice and I don't understand why.

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant Mc - assumed 'Mc' in
>   namecase.php(54) : regexp code on line 1

```
53   if( preg_match('/\bMac[A-Za-z]{2,}[^aciozj]\b/', $str) || preg_match('/\bMc/', $str) ) {
54     $str = preg_replace("/\b(Ma?c)([A-Za-z]+)/e", "$1.ucfirst('\\2')", $str);
55     // Now correct for "Mac" exceptions
56     $str = preg_replace('/\bMacEvicius/','Macevicius', $str); // Lithuanian
57     $str = preg_replace('/\bMacHado/',   'Machado', $str);    // Portuguese
58     $str = preg_replace('/\bMacHar/',    'Machar', $str);
59     ...
```

Is there anything that can be done to correct the code so it doesn't produce the notice.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote the $1 in your replacement, e.g. `"'$1'.ucfirst('\\2')"` or better yet, use `preg_replace_callback`. In PHP 5.3+ you can pass it a closure, e.g:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\b(Ma?c)([A-Za-z]+)/",
    function($m) { return $m[1] . ucfirst($m[2]); },
    $str
);
```

Comment: And before 5.3 you could already pass a closure with `create_function()`. Not as neat and 'clean' as 5.3+ closures perhaps, but still.

Comment: Tested both solutions and worked perfect!  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Correction: I meant anonymous function of course, not a closure.